# Rapports in a log file with a script shell (linux batch) and redirection

Tags: linux, file, shell, scripting, logging

Please help!!! ;)
I have a problem with this code in a batch file (Linux):

---

```
Mil=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`  
batch=`echo "${DatMusic}"`  
TabimportEnteteMusic="importentetemusic.dat"  
{  
    grep '^ENTETE' ${IMPORT}/${DatMusic} > ${IMPORT}/$TabimportEnteteMusic  
    mysql -u basemine --password="basemine" -D basemine -e "delete from importmusic;"  
    mysql -u basemine --password="basemine" -D basemine -e "delete from importentetemusic;"  
} >> $TRACES/batch/$Mil.$batch.log 2>&1
```

---

When I run this batch, its answer is:

---

```
/home/mmoine/sgbd_mysql/batch/importMusic.sh: line 51: /batch/20100319160018.afce01aa.cr.log: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type
```

______ *(in english, I suppose: "No files or Directory found")*

So, please, how can I put all generated messages in this log file?

Thanks for your answers.
Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Run with `LC_ALL=C LANG=C` to get the error message in English

Answer (score 2):

you should define your `TRACES`  variable. Also, use `$()` instead of backticks whenever possible.

```
TRACES="something here"
Mil=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
batch="${DatMusic}"
TabimportEnteteMusic="importentetemusic.dat"
{
    grep '^ENTETE' "${IMPORT}/${DatMusic}" > "${IMPORT}/$TabimportEnteteMusic"
    mysql -u basemine --password="basemine" -D basemine -e "delete from importmusic;"
    mysql -u basemine --password="basemine" -D basemine -e "delete from importentetemusic;"
} >> $TRACES/batch/${Mil}.${batch}.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thx but $TRACE is an environment variable and it exists.
:(

Comment: @Mat, `$TRACE` or `$TRACES` ?

Comment: Yes Thx for all. It was MY mistake, mea culpa...  
My error was that TRACE was defined but not TRACES, and I'm using TRACES in my script.  
Sorry for my answers, I was persuaded to make well. Thx again to you all..... and sorry for my english written ;)
Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

The error message speaks about the /batch/20100319160018.afce01aa.cr.log file.

This means that $TRACES/batch/${Mil}.${batch}.log is replaced by /batch/20100319160018.afce01aa.cr.log

This means that the $TRACES variable can't be defined at the place you are using it (event if you repeat one hundred times "$TRACE is an environment variable and is defined").

Try a

```
echo "\$TRACES $TRACES"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$TRACES/batch/$Mil.$batch.log` is becoming `/batch/20100319160018.afce01aa.cr.log` so I guess `$TRACES` isn't defined.

I guess the `/batch` directory doesn't exist.

Comment: $TRACE is an environment variable and is defined.
/batch directory was created manually before the execution of this batch.
:(
Thx anyway.